# How to response json data in springmvc

Tags: java, spring

I don't want to declare a HttpServletResponse argument in method, I get response object in LocalThread. This code work well but spring throw a exception that view not found. How to avoid declare HttpServletResponse argument and work with no warning and error.

[WARNING] /bct/user/delete.do: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/view/user/delete.jsp

```
@RequestMapping("/delete")
public void delete(String[] id) {
    //userService.delete(id);
    super.sendSuccess();
}

protected void sendSuccess(Object data, String msg) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if(data != null) {
        map.put(KEY_DATA, data);
    }
    map.put(KEY_SUCCESS, true);
    map.put(KEY_MSG, msg);
    try {
        //Jackson
        mapper.writeValue(ServletHolder.getResponse().getOutputStream(), map);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("write json fail: " + map, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at Spring MVC documentation on how to build a restful web service: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ .  Spring MVC automatically handles converting an Object to it's JSON equivalent (assuming you have Jackson as a dependency) when you use @RestController.

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody). It describes how to response a json, but to do this you should have the jackson dependency like @alfredaday said.